# How can I read an unreadable USB stick?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I have a USB stick which cannot be read by either Windows or Ubuntu. It is not damaged as far as I can tell and I have used it in the past.

The "Disks" app in Ubuntu results is shown in the screenshot. `gparted` and `fdisk -l` do not find it.

Results of "Disks" in Ubuntu:

[image: results of "Disks" in Ubuntu.]

It does appear in the Windows Device Manager but not in the Windows Explorer (or whatever the file manager is called these days).

How can I access, read, format it, etc? Thanks.

Comment: “It is not damaged as far as I can tell and I have used it in the past.” You used it in the past, but the past is not the present… USB flash drives are commodity items and die frequently. Sorry to say, but it’s most likely dead.